# Limit Functionality with Android Subscriptions

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, billing, in-app-subscription

I am trying to create a in-app billing for android application that will allow users to buy a subscription. I have managed to do that and I am able to buy subscriptions but what I don't get is how can I limit some features in app to those who have not subscribed?

I cant seem to find any tutorials on that. What I want is on a button press if user have not subscribed prompt a in-app billing window. I can achieve that with this code.

```
public void launchBillingFLow(@SkuType String skuType, String productId) {

    Runnable launchBillingRequest = () -> {

        BillingFlowParams mBillingFlowParams;

        mBillingFlowParams = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder()
                .setSku(productId)
                .setType(skuType)
                .build();

        mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow((Activity) context, mBillingFlowParams);

    };

    executeServiceRequest(launchBillingRequest);

}
```

But what if user have already subscribed? So the question is, how can I check if user is subscribed and execute button press and if not show billing window. Can I get that information only if user is connected to the Internet? Do I need to store that information on device?

Comment: I believe you should use queryPurchases, it uses Google Play cache without initiating a network request. So you will be able to know who bought which product and then make limited access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Subscription methods to get the purchase details -

1. To check if a subscription is already purchased (responseCode == 7)
2. Get all the puschase list using purchasesResult.getPurchasesList()
3. Get the response just after successful parchase of a subscription using onPurchasesUpdated method
4. Show In-App Billing Flow using BillingFlowParams.Builder

   ```
       mBillingClient.startConnection(new BillingClientStateListener() {
               @Override
               public void onBillingSetupFinished(@BillingClient.BillingResponse int billingResponseCode) {

                   if (billingResponseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK) {
                       // The billing client is ready. You can query purchases here.

                       final Purchase.PurchasesResult purchasesResult = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
                       for (Purchase sourcePurchase : purchasesResult.getPurchasesList()) {
                           if (sourcePurchase != null) {

                               ConsumeResponseListener listener = new ConsumeResponseListener() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onConsumeResponse(final int responseCode, final String purchaseToken) {
                                       // Log.d("anupam2", responseCode + "  <------->  "+ purchasesResult.getPurchasesList() + "  <------->  " + purchaseToken);
                                   }
                               };
                               mBillingClient.consumeAsync(sourcePurchase.getPurchaseToken(), listener);
                           } else {

                           }
                       }

                       if (purchasesResult.getPurchasesList().size() > 0) {
                           //  Log.d("anupam3", purchasesResult.getPurchasesList().size() + "");

                       } else {
                           //  Log.d("anupam4", purchasesResult.getPurchasesList().size() + "");
                           BillingFlowParams.Builder builder = BillingFlowParams.newBuilder().setSku("234r23446").setType(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
                           int responseCode = mBillingClient.launchBillingFlow(SplashActivity.this, builder.build());
                           if (responseCode == 7) {

                               //Item already purchased
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }

               @Override
               public void onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
                   // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
                   // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
                   Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           });

   mBillingClient = BillingClient.newBuilder(this).setListener(new PurchasesUpdatedListener() {
               @Override
               public void onPurchasesUpdated(int responseCode, @Nullable List<Purchase> purchases) {

                   //  Log.d("anupam", responseCode + "");
                   if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.OK && purchases != null) {
                       for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                       //List of purchases
                       }
                   } else if (responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponse.USER_CANCELED) {
                       Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Sorry, you have canceled purchase Subscription.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   } else {
                       Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, "Sorry, some error occurred.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }
               }
           }).build();
   ```

Now what you can do is call this in your splashscreen and save a value using sharedpreference or a global variable in your app based on the response code. Check if the response code is 7 for your subscription id or not. If suscribed (for responseCode == 7, you saved the value as suscribed), show premium features else not.

Hope it helps!